# Can anyone tell me the reason why suddenly I am facing this problem?

Tags: javascript

I have simple code:

```
var aso=document.querySelector("body");
aso.style.background="yellow";
```

This is written in separate .js file. When you open the page, it is showing error:

```
simple.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at simple.js:2
```

But when I run this code in console window, it works fine, but showing error in separate JS file.

Comment: make sure you run this code after document load complete.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are linking your JS file in the HTML file before the DOM is loaded, so your query selector can't find desired element.

Try to move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the HTML file.

Comment: Thnku for clearing a basic problem

Answer (score 0):

its a dom problem you must run scripts after dom loaded there are many ways to execute js functions after dom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // self executing function here
    (function() {
       // your page initialization code here
       // the DOM will be available here
        var aso=document.querySelector("body");
        aso.style.background="yellow";
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
    var aso=document.querySelector("body");
        aso.style.background="yellow";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnku bhai @Dev Khalil